# Oracle DB link connection config files

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create distributed db and create snapshots in oracle. I placed db on two laptops in one local network. I tried to edit two config files (tnsnames.ora and listener.ora) and created db link using alias in tnsnames.ora. But if I try run select refer to second database, oracle throw Ora-12541: TNS - no listener. Can you help me to resolve this problem?

My tnsnames.ora file:

PC1 ip 192.168.1.100

```
MIRASCONNECT =  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.103)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = orl)
)  )
```

PC2 ip 192.168.1.103

```
mirassecond =  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = database)
)  )
```

in listener.ora i tried to edit only sid name:

PC1:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =  (SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = database) (GLOBAL_DBNAME = database)
  (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Piotrek\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Piotrek\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)  )
```

PC2:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = orl) (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orl)
  (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Piotrek\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Piotrek\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)  )
```

create dblink:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK MIRAS_CONNECTION CONNECT TO MIREK IDENTIFIED BY pwdmirek USING 'MIRASCONNECT'
```

and my select looks like:

```
select * from test_table@miras_connection
```

Answer (score 0):

No listener is easy to understand.
U did not start your listener on 192.168.1.103

Try

```
lsnrctl start
```